# When opening a FCM received with getInitialMessage, flutter_native_splash is not displayed

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter app development.
I am currently able to receive FirebaseCloudMessaging notifications.
It is also possible to display a splash screen using flutter_native_splash.
So we have a problem.
When the app is in taskkill state, the splash screen is not displayed only when I click on a notification to launch the app.(getInitialMessage)
By the way, the splash screen is displayed when the app is launched normally.
Here is an excerpt of the program code
I would be happy to know the cause of the problem.

```
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      if(message != null){
        setFCM(message).then((void v) {
          getFCMList("all").then((void v) {
            setState(() {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/fcmmessage',
                arguments: FcmMessageArguments(_fcmList[0], true),);
            });
          });
        });
      }
    });
```

```
    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
      ...
```

I tried intentionally executing FlutterNativeSplash.preserve within initState and getInitialMessage, but the splash screen still did not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [this is the intended behavior](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199776339#comment3) in Android 12.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thanks to you I got the hint and solved the problem.
I followed the following site and it solved the problem.
https://zenn.dev/flutteruniv_dev/articles/326d690f6efdbd

In the "AndroidManifest.xml", I added the "meta-data"
SplashScreenDrawable" in "io.flutter.embedding.android.
Sorry about that.